# Declaring a statically initialized struct in GNU as (M68K)

Tags: assembly, gnu, 68000

So according to the GNU docs I declare a struct like this:

```
.struct 0
MY_Member1: .struct MY_Member1+4
MY_Member2: .struct MY_Member2+1
MY_Member3: .struct MY_Member3+1
MY_Member4: .struct MY_Member4+2
MYStruct: .struct MYStruct ; This should give me the size of my struct
```

And in my code I can access a member like this:

```
move.l Ptr,a0
move.w MyMember4(a0),d0
...
```

But how do I declare a global variable with a structure initalizing it's members. In C/C++ I would write it like this:

```
static MyStruct name = { &value, value, ... };
```

How can I achive this in GNU AS?

i.E. something like:

```
MyStaticStruct: 
MY_Member1 = ptr
MY_Member2 = $10
MY_Member3 = 'a'
Remainder defaults to 0 but the space is reserved for the full structure.
```

Comment: You need to initialize all the memory directly, without referencing field names. E.g. `.int ptr; .byte 10, 'a', 0, 0`

Comment: You can of course use `.byte`, `.short`, `.long` or whatever to emit static data, and then accesses it using struct syntax.   IDK if there's a way to have the definition itself "type safe" or anything.

Comment: Thanks. I feared as much. Of course I can emit static data, but I thought that the assembler might aid a little bit. I guess it's a hint, that there is not even a real "struct" directive.